# Convert and check string to special format in hta

Tags: javascript, vbscript, hta

I create one text-area in HTA file there fill for example:

```
------------------------------
| test@stackoverflow.com     |
| test@superuser.com         |
| stackoverflow.com          |
| stackapps.com              |
------------------------------    
                     Submit
```

I Want when click on submit with that filled data to create two output files:

1.txt

```
3|100|test@stackoverflow.com|0|0|6:1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,9|7:1,10,11,13,16,2,4,5,6,9|
3|100|test@superuser.com|0|0|6:1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,9|7:1,10,11,13,16,2,4,5,6,9|
1|100|stackoverflow.com|0|0|6:1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,9|7:1,10,11,13,16,2,4,5,6,9|
1|100|stackapps.com|0|0|6:1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,9|7:1,10,11,13,16,2,4,5,6,9|
```

2.txt

```
WF,test@stackoverflow.com
WF,test@stackoverflow.com
WF,*@stackoverflow.com
WF,*@stackapps.com
```

It's hard to me to convert the pipeline and WF,*@ when script see only domain not e-mail.

Comment: Where do the other values in `1.txt` come from?

Comment: I want to add that values to the file actually.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. At least the first field doesn't seem to be static (some lines have the value `1`, others the value `3`), so how do you determine which value goes into which line? Are all the other fields static, i.e. do they have the same values for each line?